# Top n from each group in Access query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Could anyone help me modifying given below query:

```
SELECT 
    TabA.[02-Issuing_country_name], 
    TabA.[01-Issuing_zone], 
    TabA.[06-Year], 
    TabA.[07-Month], 
    TabA.[code], 
    Sum(TabA.[Fare]) AS Spend 
INTO SPEND_BY_Groups
FROM TabA
WHERE (((TabA.[05-Travel_type])="Air"))
GROUP BY 
    TabA.[02-Issuing_country_name], 
    TabA.[01-Issuing_zone], 
    TabA.[06-Year], 
    TabA.[07-Month], TabA.[code]
ORDER BY 
    TabA.[02-Issuing_country_name], 
    TabA.[06-Year],
    TabA.[07-Month], 
    Sum(TabA.[Fare]) DESC;
```

to show top 3 (by Fare) for each group.

I was reading some similar posts but have some problems with applying the solutions from there.

Best regards and may the force be with you!

Edit:

I deleted  part it was irrelevant.

Comment: Why do you sort by country, year and month if you are inserting the records into a table? If you sort by sum(fare) then you can wrap the query in a subquery and just select top(3) *.....

Comment: Hey, The data must by divided  into groups like this: Country->year->month, so for one given country and 4 years of data i must have 48 records (x3 of top 3 fare by code). I know the sorting then has no need i just wanted to see it in a certain order to be able to check if I am getting a correct answer.